# sharing user on 2 WordPress installs in 2 sub domains on same server

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have 2 WordPress sites in 2 different sub-domains like **test1.abc.com** and **test2.abc.com** . Both sites have wp-require plugin activated and only logged-in users can see the site. We want to make a system where if a user logged into one site, he should be auto-login into the other one.

**What i try :**

After some searching I know I need to use one database for both sites. So I have done these steps:

I have download the whole database of test2.abc.com site and change all prefix wp_ to wpmo_, replaced it in whole database and upload it into first site's database.
I added these 2 lines in wp-config.php of the second site, to define that second site should use first site's user table not its own.

```
define('CUSTOM_USERMETA_TABLE', 'wp_usermeta');
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'wp_users');
```

Now, the second site is using the first site's users and I am able to login to the second site by the user details of first site.

The next problem is cookies, so I added these lines in wp-config of both sites.

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.abc.com');
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('COOKIEHASH', 'aee53c017c29dc0d3ae37253fc8cbfd8');
```

Now I logged in into test1.abc.com and when I go to test2.abc.com , it asks me to login. That means cookies are not passing from the first site to the second one. However, i tried to be print $_COOKIE and it gives me same encrypt values, but user still not auto login on second site. also when i came back to first site , it automatic logout. i feel like both sites are related somehow on cookies and i am close but still not reached to my goal of auto login into second site.

Any help?

**Solution :**

After some help from Mikk3lRo and others, i have managed to solve this issue. i am posting the solution for anyone who faces the same problem.
here you can find step by step guide for this :

**step 1:** use one database for both installations, install 2 wp by using 2 different prefix on installation time.

**step 2:** Make sure that the randomly generated secret keys and salts are also identical in both wp-config.php files.

**step 3:** paste these 2 lines in wp-config.php of second site.

```
//Share user tables
define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'SITE1_PREFIX_usermeta');
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'SITE1_PREFIX_users');
```

**step 4:** share cookies with these lines . (write in both wp-config.php)

```
//Share cookies
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.abc.com');
define('COOKIEHASH', 'aee53c017c29dc0d3ae37253fc8cbfd8');
```

**step 5:** now you will be able to auto login in second site when logged into first site. but your will an error message on second site "you do not have permission to access this page", which is a good thing.

**step 6:** The reason is, WordPress checks the user capability (wp-includes/capabilities.php) so either you have directly add this capability in database (in case you only have few users) or to write a plugin for this. @Mikk3lRo writes a plugin for this in comments, which is Good.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', false);` ?

Comment: Just tried, no luck. well, i think COOKIE_DOMAIN should be common in both wp installs.

Comment: Is there any reason you haven't accepted my answer?

Answer (score 7):

Alright - you are very close, but there are a few more things to be done.

All requirements are as follows:

- Share the same database, using different prefixes - you've done this. From here I assume the prefixes are `wp1_`, `wp2_` and so on.
- Share the `wp1_users` and `wp1_usermeta` tables - you've done this - and actually you would have overcome this obstacle if only you had spelled the constants name correctly... it's `CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE` (one more underscore than what you have)
- Share cookies between the subdomains using a common `COOKIE_DOMAIN` and `COOKIEHASH` - you've done this
- Make sure that the (normally) randomly generated secret keys and salts are also identical - you don't write that you've done this, but judging by your results I think either you have or your keys are empty (which is not good, but will work)
- Make sure there's a `prefix_capabilities` entry for each user for each site in the shared `usermeta` table - I don't think you've done this, simply because you haven't yet reached the point where you realize it's necessary.

### Complete solution:

This goes in `wp-config.php`:

```
//Share user tables
define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'wp1_usermeta');
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'wp1_users');

//Share cookies
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.abc.com');
define('COOKIEHASH', 'aee53c017c29dc0d3ae37253fc8cbfd8');

/**
 * In my case these are not needed - but they may well be if one
 * of the installs is located in a sub-folder. I have not tested
 * this theory though.
 */
//define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
//define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/');
//define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/wp-admin');

//These all need to be identical
define('AUTH_KEY', 'this should be random');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY', 'this should also be a random string');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY', 'one more random string');
define('AUTH_SALT', 'oh my - so many random strings');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'salt, salt, salt and no eggs');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT', 'this is sooooo random');

/**
 * These do not need to be shared - in fact they probably shouldn't be
 * - if they are you could (in theory) do actions on one site that was
 * intended for the other - probably not a very big concern in reality
 */
define('NONCE_KEY', 'these should be random too, but can differ');
define('NONCE_SALT', 'one site has one, the other another');
```

This is enough to get you logged in on both sites - but there's still that last annoying bullet left on the list.

The problem is that your permissions ("capabilities") are only good on one of the sites because the `meta_key` is prefixed with the table prefix of the site. If you google around a bit you will find lots of solutions recommending to modify `wp-includes/capabilities.php` to just use a common prefix instead - I strongly recommend against that! (not for security reasons, but because you will need to make this patch / hack after every update... and it's just insanely bad practice to modify core files)

Instead to remedy this obstacle you need to duplicate the `wp1_capabilities` row in the `wp1_usermeta` table (for each user!), giving it a new `umeta_id` and substituting the table prefix `wp1_` with `wp2_` in the `meta_key` column. You need to do this for each site, so you have one row with `meta_key` `wp1_capabilities`, one with `wp2_capabilities` and so on.

If you and a friend of yours are the only users who'll ever log in to the sites, then just do it by hand through phpMyAdmin or something - if you need it to work dynamically, then it should be quite possible to automate with a small plugin (see edit below).

I've always hated this design - a table prefix has no business inside a table row! I think it is needed for multisite installs, though I'm sure there would be other (better) ways to solve it...

### Update: Plugin to keep user roles synchronized between all sites

This simple plugin will duplicate and keep the required rows in the `usermeta` table updated when users are created or edited.

One thing worth noting is that it probably won't work with multisite installs because they have some special capabilities / roles. I have not tested this.

It may need refinement for specific use cases (please do comment), but it does the job fine for my limited test case that only includes a few users. It will be inefficient for a site with thousands of users, but as it only runs when a user is modified, and only does updates if they are needed I doubt this will be a major concern. However it should be relatively easy to adapt to only read and modify the user that was just added / edited. It would complicate initial setup a bit though, as pre-existing users would not automatically get duplicated on the first run.

Create the folder `wp-content/plugins/duplicate-caps` and inside put the following in `duplicate-caps.php` - and don't forget to activate under `plugins` in wordpress admin. It needs to be installed on all sites.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Duplicate Caps
Plugin URI: 
Description: Tiny plugin to duplicate capabilities in a setup where users (and user tables) are shared across more than one install
Author: Mikk3lRo
Version: 0.1
Author URI: 
*/
$dummy = new duplicate_caps();
class duplicate_caps {
    function __construct() {
        add_action('updated_user_meta', array($this, 'update_prefixed_caps'), 10, 2);
        add_action('added_user_meta', array($this, 'update_prefixed_caps'), 10, 2);
        add_action('deleted_user_meta', array($this, 'update_prefixed_caps'), 10, 2);
    }
    function update_prefixed_caps($mid, $object_id) {
        /**
         * Note that $object_id contains the id of the user that was
         * just changed.
         * On a site with many users it would make sense to only
         * get and set information regarding the just-changed user
         * Currently this function corrects roles for all users
         * making sure pre-existing users are duplicated, and keeping
         * the table in sync.
         */
        global $wpdb;
        //Quick and dirty - get all *capabilities rows for all users
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '%capabilities'";
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

        //Will hold all prefixes (always include our own)
        $prefixes = array($wpdb->prefix);

        //Will grab the existing role for each prefix
        $user_roles = array();

        //Loop our results
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            //Make sure the meta_key looks right, and grab the prefix
            if (preg_match('#^(.*)capabilities$#', $result->meta_key, $matches)) {
                $prefix = $matches[1];

                // Collect prefixes
                $prefixes[] = $prefix;

                //Note the entire row for later use
                $user_roles[$result->user_id][$prefix] = $result;
            }
        }

        //Make sure we only have one of each
        $prefixes = array_unique($prefixes);

        //Loop through the users we found
        foreach ($user_roles as $user_id => $existing_prefixes) {
            if (!isset($existing_prefixes[$wpdb->prefix])) {
                //User was probably just deleted - all rows are deleted by
                //wordpress though, so no cleanup for us :)
            } else {
                //We want all prefixes to obey us (we just created or changed
                //the user, so we want that to affect all sites)
                $desired_role = $existing_prefixes[$wpdb->prefix]->meta_value;

                //Loop through all prefixes
                foreach ($prefixes as $prefix) {
                    //Data to be inserted / updated
                    $cap_data = array(
                        'user_id' => $user_id,
                        'meta_key' => $prefix . 'capabilities',
                        'meta_value' => $desired_role
                    );

                    //If the prefix doesn't exist for this user
                    if (!in_array($prefix, array_keys($existing_prefixes))) {
                        //Actually insert it (user was probably just created)
                        $wpdb->insert($wpdb->usermeta, $cap_data, array('%d', '%s', '%s'));
                    } else if ($desired_role !== $existing_prefixes[$prefix]->meta_value) {
                        //Update it if not already correct (user was probably just edited)
                        $cap_data['umeta_id'] = $existing_prefixes[$prefix]->umeta_id;
                        $wpdb->replace($wpdb->usermeta, $cap_data, array('%d', '%s', '%s', '%d'));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not wokring, i did the same : it's CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE (one more underscore than what you have) : done, Make sure that the (normally) randomly generated secret keys and salts are also identical: yes, they are. I will go for capabilities issues later, but it still don't give me capability error on second site. i am logged in first site as user, go to second in new tab, still wants me to login :( . i will solve the capability issue, if once i got that error message.

Comment: I have this working on the exact setup you describe. Two fresh wordpress installs, each on its own sub-domain. Log in to one and you are logged in on the other. What exactly do you mean by "the same"?

Comment: Don not know what i am doing wrong. i have 2 latest wp installs on 2 subdomains (2 folders). sharing same key and salt strings, same user and user meta table, same cookie domain and hash key. I am logged in to test1.abc.com and than open test2.abc.com in new tab like test2.abc.com/wp-admin, it still asked me to login.

Comment: i just got permission error message on second site , i checked by removing this line , define('COOKIEPATH', '/'); let me fix the capability issue, i think it will done after that.

Comment: Hi @Mikk3lRo, thank you for your help. i got it done now. Bounty is yours. Happy coding!!

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's working. How Can I add Links of all related sub-domain link's in header ? so user can choose site for login after login in one site.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the easiest solution for you would be to make use of one of WordPress' single-sign on (SSO) plugins.

There's a large amount of plugins listed [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/single-sign-on).

You could use one of them or base your authentication on one of them.

Alternately there's [multi-site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) which will let you create a network of sites, if you decide to create a multi-site, then please read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network) first.

Comment: Thanks for reply, can't use multisite now as site's are running on separate databases for a long time. the plugins also not useful in my situation. i am expecting some answer on Cookies related.

Comment: The functionality you are describing is single-sign on (SSO), are you sure none of the plugins fit?

Comment: i did, this doesn't seems to be reliable. plugin has 1 rating out of 5 and too bed reviews. "this script is stealing your wordpress and whmcs username password hash other information. don't use it." i have sites with thousand of users, not sure to use this plugin.

Answer (score -1):

I think define cookies is not enough to login to wp site.

So my solution is, Create a plugin to restrict access to those who don't login to one of the site.
Set a cookie when user login to one of the site.
when user view the site. check the cookie value, and redirect or return to the site.

**Sample Code:**

```
 add_action('wp_login','prefix_set_cookie'); //when someone logged in this call the set_cookie function

 function prefix_set_cookie(){
    setcookie('hashed_cookie','my_value'); //set the cookie

 }

 //call check_cookie function when wordpress site loads
 add_action('wp','check_cookie');

 function check_cookie(){
    //check the cookie value and view the website
    if(isset($_COOKIE['hashed_cookie'] )){
        if($_COOKIE['hashed_cookie'] == 'my_value'){
         return;            
        }else{
            die("no access please login <a href='your login link'>LINK</a>");
        }
    }
 }
```

Main drawback with this plugin is poor security. anyone create this cookie manually. so its high security one, don't use this. try to hash the cookie as possible so it can't easily created manually.

( if you want full code for the plugin ill put somewhere )

**Update (full plugin):**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Restrict Access
Author: Pasindu Jayawardane
Description: This Plugin Restrict Access to the Site without login
Author URI: https://www.facebook.com/pj.pasiya
*/

 $key = hash('md5','restrict_access');
 $value = hash('md5','true');

 add_action('wp_login','es_set_cookie');

 function es_set_cookie(){
    global $key, $value;

    setcookie($key, $value ,time()+3600);

 }

 add_action('wp_logout','es_remove_cookie');

 function es_remove_cookie(){
    global $key, $value;

    setcookie($key, $value ,time()-3600);
 }

 add_action('wp','es_check_cookie');

 function es_check_cookie(){
    global $key, $value;

    if(isset($_COOKIE[$key] )){
        if($_COOKIE[$key] == $value){
         return;            
        }else{
            ?>
            <h1 class="alert alert-danger">
                This Website is Protected! <small>You Must Login to See the Website</small>
            </h1>
            <p class="ra-login"> <a href="<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?>"> Login </a> <p>
        <?php

            die();
        }
    }else{
        ?>
        <h1 class="alert alert-danger">
            This Website is Protected! <small>You Must Login to See the Website</small>
        </h1>
        <p class="ra-login"> <a href="<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?>"> Login </a> <p>
        <?php

        die();
    }
 }
```

go to your wordpress installation plugins directory ({{wp install folder}}->wp-content->plugins and make a new file with extension .php {{file-restrict.php}} copy and paste this code

do this for both sites

go to wordpress plugins and activate the plugin. (both sites)

once you login to one of the site you can view either of site. and once you logout one site it gives a message with a link to login to the site.

(after you activate just logout and login to the site)

i'll email the code for you too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. seems like it can work, you can send me any help on gaurav.tyagi@techstriker.com
Bounty will be yours , once i get it done.

Comment: Sure, give me a moment.

Comment: I don't see how this solves the issue. It just shows a message to users that aren't already logged in to go log in (on whatever site they are on). The idea as I understood was to only protect one of the sites, and send people to login only on the other - then redirect back to the one they came from - this is nowhere in the code, and even if it did work like that, users would not actually be logged in on the unprotected site - meaning commenting etc. would only be possible anonymously. It also creates invalid HTML (ie. `die()` in `wp` hook means no `<html>`, `<body>`, stylesheets etc.).

Comment: @Mikk3IRo  User wants to view the site after login, and restrict who are not login to the website, that's what wp-require to add Restricted Site Access plugin. but also he wants view the second website after login to the first one. this plugin allow user to login to one site and view the content also if you go to next site. it store the cookie so it sees that website too. about invalid html. the webpage will compile the message without any error as text file. This solution is simple and no need any third party plugins. but this plugin will not auto login to wordpress site just allow them tovie

Comment: This is something like i did with php refrer (also not secure way), but here is one problem, i need user to login in second site (not only able to see). The reason is, users will add posts and can comment on posts by others. with this code, they are able to see the site but not actually logged in.

Comment: @user3333933 you were talking about some third party plugin, can you give me link or name of such plugins which can do this functionality, that will be very helpful .

Comment: Hi, yes, user actually not logged in just store a cookie to track whether
 user login or not. if that's what you looking for. just to view the website. & this is the plugin link https://wordpress.org/plugins/restricted-site-access/