# Several wordpress sites access only for custom role

Tags: php, wordpress, roles

I have two websites (Site A + Site B) that both run on WordPress. On Site A, there are several roles including Role X. I need to grant access to Site B, but only for users from Site A that have Role X.

I thought about copying all the database tables with users information from Site A's database to Site B's while restricting access on Site B only for Role X. This seems inconvenient because I don't know when new users appear on site A, which means I will just have to run this manual copying process again.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Probably your Q is duplicate of one of this (will depend on how your sites are setup): http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=CUSTOM_USER_TABLE%20%5bwordpress%5d

Comment: @brasofilo yeah, smells similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30952936/sharing-user-on-2-wordpress-installs-in-2-sub-domains-on-same-server) but such solution cause some security problems. My second website contains some confidential information, so if intruder will get access to my first database, he immediately will get access to confidential, what i don't want to happen =)

Comment: For now solution is: I copy all the user database table from one site to another everyday by cron and then add subscriber role to all the users.